# How can I define a Right and Bottom property in PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, position, powerpoint, collision-detection

I'm very new to coding. Having said that, here's my problem:

I'm trying to define a new "bottom" and "right" property using the "left", "top", "width", and "height" properties for some collision detection code I'm trying to write, but I can't seem to get the syntax right. It keeps coming back with error messages when I run the code like "Compile error: Method or data member not found" for the ".Bottom" and ".Right" properties. Moreover, if I comment them out to try to find out more about the nature of the error, it returns a "Run-time error'91': Object variable or With block variable not set."

Any insight you can offer would be greatly appreciated. The code follows:

```
Sub getPosition()

    Dim sl As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    
    Dim Left, Right, Bottom, Top, Width, Height As Double
        
    Right = shp.Left - shp.Width
    Bottom = shp.Top - shp.Height
    
    Set shp = ActivePresentation.Slides(18).Shapes("Group 96")
    
    Debug.Print shp.Top
    Debug.Print shp.Bottom
    
    Debug.Print shp.Left
    Debug.Print shp.Right
    
    Debug.Print shp.Width
    Debug.Print shp.Height

End Sub
```

Comment: "Method or data member not found" means the `shp` object has no `Bottom` or `Right` property.  You can't create them by declaring a Bottom/Right variable - those are not connected to the `shp` object...   You also can't do this `shp.Left - shp.Width` when shp is not pointing at an actual Shape.

Comment: FYI `Dim Left, Right, Bottom, Top, Width, Height As Double` declares all variables except for `Height` as `Variant`.  In VBA every variable needs to be assigned a type, or it defaults to Variant.

Comment: As explained by Tim Williams, you can't just declare variables if you want to add properties to an existing Object class. The only thing I can think of would be to create a custom Class, and recreate the original object but add your new properties. You could accomplish most of it by having your new class initialize one of the old classes and pass all the properties to it except the new properties, which are handled by your new class.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to declare specific Functions that provide the values that those properties would provide if they existed. For example:

```
Function ShapeRight(shp As Shape) As Single
    ShapeRight = shp.Left + shp.Width
End Function
```

And

```
Function ShapeBottom(shp As Shape) As Single
    ShapeBottom = shp.Top + shp.Height
End Function
```

You could then use these like this (assuming you have put them in a standard Module):

```
    Debug.Print shp.Top
    Debug.Print ShapeBottom(shp)
    
    Debug.Print shp.Left
    Debug.Print ShapeRight(shp)
    
    Debug.Print shp.Width
    Debug.Print shp.Height
```

Comment: Nice!  The only change I'd suggest is to declare your variables as Singles rather than as Doubles. All coordinates in PPT are Singles.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg ... you're right ... amended!